# How to fetch browse ranking by API in CMS (Nuxt.js + WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, nuxt.js

I create a CMS for a blog on Nuxt.js (On the front end).
The CMS uses WordPress as its backend and uses the 'WP REST API' to display articles in Nuxt.js.
(Because I want to reduce the time spent creating the management screen with WordPress.)

There are feature that need to be implemented here. 
It is the article browsing ranking.

Use the following plug-ins and code to retrieve articles from the site in order of number of views.

Plugin:
WordPress Popular Posts
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

I added the following code to functions.php on WordPress

```
class WPP_REST_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->namespace     = '/wpp';
        $this->resource_name = '/posts';
    }

    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route( $this->namespace , $this->resource_name, array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => array($this, 'get_wpp'),
        ) );
    }


    public function get_wpp( $request ) {
        if (function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular')) {
            $args = array(
                'limit' => 10,
                'stats_views' => 0,
                'wpp_start' => '{',
                'wpp_end' => '}',
                'post_html' => '{pid},',
            );
            ob_start();
            wpp_get_mostpopular( $args );
            $str = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            $str = str_replace("\n", '', $str);
            preg_match('/\{(([0-9]*,)*)\}/s', $str, $match);
            if (count($match)) {
                $ids = rtrim($match[1], ',');
                $url = get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=' . $ids;
                header("Location: " . $url);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}


function prefix_register_my_rest_routes() {
    $controller = new WPP_REST_Controller();
    $controller->register_routes();
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'prefix_register_my_rest_routes' );
```

Nuxt.js(ranking.vue):

```
<template>
  {{top_articles}}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      top_articles
    };
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const top_articles = await $axios.$get('http://example.com/wp-json/wpp/posts');
}
</script>
```

But there's a problem.
The number of articles viewed via Nuxt.js is not reflected in the API responses.

The article display page looks like this:

Nuxt.js(article/_id.vue)

```
<template>
  {{ article }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      article: this.article,
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const article = await $axios.$get('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + params.id);
    return { article };
  }
}
<script>
```

Please tell me what I should do to achieve the above.
(I can use other plug-ins.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself.
The WordPress Popular Posts plug-in had a way to count up your browsing via the API.

Reference URL:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpp-with-an-ajax-based-site/

I revised "article/_ id.vue" as follows.

```
<template>
  {{ article }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      article: this.article,
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const article = await $axios.$get('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + params.id);

    // WordPress Popular Posts Counts Up Visits
    $axios.$post(
      'http://example.com/wp-json/wordpress-popular-posts/v1/popular-posts?wpp_id=' +
        params.id,
    )

    return { article };
  }
}
<script>
```